# Linkedin gem - Company Updates API - read multiple companies with one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, linkedin-api

I'm using the linkedin gem https://github.com/hexgnu/linkedin

This work fine when I try to get a single company details:

```
client = LinkedIn::Client.new
company = client.company(:id=>("1058"), :fields=> %w(name employee-count-range ))
```

How can I use the Companies API for read multiple companies details in a single API call?

According to Linkedin API, it is possible:
http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields

I also found this answer but I'm not sure that the gem support it:
https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/company-updates-api-read-multiple-companies-one-query

Thanks in advance